# Encoder VHDL Code

Tags: vhdl

```
-- Code your design here

library IEEE;

use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity encoder8_3 is

     port(

         din : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);

         dout : out INTEGER RANGE 0 TO 15

         );

end encoder8_3;

architecture encoder8_3_arc of encoder8_3 is

begin

    dout <= "0" when (din="10000000") else
            "1" when (din="01000000") else
            "2" when (din="00100000") else
            "3" when (din="00010000") else
            "4" when (din="00001000") else
            "5" when (din="00000100") else
            "6" when (din="00000010") else
            "7";

end encoder8_3_arc;
```

Will this code run?I want to return the integers in place of its binary equivalent.

Comment: what is the question ?

Answer (score 1):

Why won't this code *compile*?

Because *integer literals* in VHDL do not have quotes:

```
library IEEE;

use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity encoder8_3 is

     port(

         din : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);

         dout : out INTEGER RANGE 0 TO 15

         );

end encoder8_3;

architecture encoder8_3_arc of encoder8_3 is

begin

    dout <= 0 when (din="10000000") else
            1 when (din="01000000") else
            2 when (din="00100000") else
            3 when (din="00010000") else
            4 when (din="00001000") else
            5 when (din="00000100") else
            6 when (din="00000010") else
            7;

end encoder8_3_arc;
```

http://www.edaplayground.com/x/5f2M

Answer (score 1):

you have to remove the quotes around the integer values:

```
dout <= 0 when (din="10000000") else
        1 when (din="01000000") else
        2 when (din="00100000") else
        3 when (din="00010000") else
        4 when (din="00001000") else
        5 when (din="00000100") else
        6 when (din="00000010") else
        7;
```

Running a simple testbench here: http://www.edaplayground.com/x/5bwv I got the following output:

[image]